# ODBC Driver Version 03.86.3959 connection to SQL Server 2014

Tags: odbc, sql-server-2014

Ok so I have some accounting software running on a Windows Server 2003 box. This server uses a System DSN, that uses Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 03.86.3959 to connect to a Management Information System, which is running on SQL Server 2014 on a Windows Server 2012R2 box.

I create the System DSN from scratch using the ODBC Data Source Administrator. I have tried both integrated security and the `sa` login for SQL Server 2014. Both these are set up correctly as logins on the SQL Server with linked users. I have also tried putting the server as the IP and the dns name.

When I try to run the connection test, I get an "SSL Security Error".

I can ping the 2012R2 box from the 2003 box.

So I am wondering whether I need to update the ODBC driver on the Server 2003 box to ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. The problem is that the system requirements for this ODBC driver do not include Windows Server 2003 -- only Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2 are listed as supported operating systems.

I have searched online for some compatibility charts with ODBC drivers and SQL Server versions but have not been able to come up with anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was what I thought. I updated the ODBC driver on the Server 2003 to the one in the Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 SP2 Feature Pack and it worked fine. This version of the ODBC driver was old enough to work on Windows Server 2003 but yet new enough to be able to connect to SQL Server 2014.